# DAX - create a new table from two inputs

Tags: powerbi, dax

There is a table Mapping listing Sites and Services, it looks something like:

```
 Site | Service
 A    | LAN
 A    | WAN
 A    | Desktop
 B    | LAN
 B    | WAN
 B    | MainF
```

There is a table Data, with columns Service, Start, End:

```
 Service | Start | End
 LAN     | 1-Jan | 2-Jan
 WAN     | 3-Jan | 4-Jan
 Desktop | 5-Jan | 6-Jan
 MainF   | 7-Jan | 8-Jan
 Desktop | 9-Jan |10-Jan
 MainF   |11-Jan |12-Jan
```

The join between both tables is many-to-many on Service

Using DAX only I would like to create a new table listing Start and End dates against Sites, not services, so the output would be like:

```
 Site | Service
 A    | 1-Jan 
 A    | 3-Jan
 A    | 5-Jan
 A    | 9-Jan
 B    | 1-Jan
 B    | 3-Jan
 B    | 7-Jan
 B    |11-Jan
```

I can easily create this table using a build in visualisation but I would like to create a new table using DAX only.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/crossjoin-function-dax

Comment: @Anonymous Not even close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAX actually allows for a left-outer join, which is what you are doing here.

```
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN ( 'Sites and Services', Data ),
    "Site", [Site],
    "Service", [Start]
)
```

This will work so long as there is at least one matching column between the left and right tables (in this case, `Service`). The wrapping `SelectColumns()` just discards the unused columns (`End` & `Site`).

Comment: Nice. Yes, you are right, at the end is just a left outer join. I got “confused” by the mentioning of m:n and did not spend any time to think through. Lesson learnt.

Comment: No worries! Working with table manipulations in DAX is definitely a steep learning curve because it is harder to see what steps the calculation is taking. Would definitely recommend trying out DAX Studio. It will make testing your DAX a lot easier and help with debugging.

Comment: @michalrosa, if this solved your question, be sure to mark it as accepted! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After a painful period of trial, error and working from examples, I have come up with the monstrosity listed below.  It seems to work but it's also quite ugly.  Any ideas on how to make it look smarter would be appreciated.

```
 Outages by site = 
 var tbl = GENERATE(
     SUMMARIZE(Mapping,Mapping[Site]),
     var sit = Mapping[Site]
     var ser = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Mapping[Service]),Mapping[Site]=sit)
     RETURN
         ADDCOLUMNS(
             FILTER(
                 Data,
                 CONTAINS(ser,Mapping[Service], Data[Service])
             ),
             "Col", 1))
 return

 SUMMARIZE(
     tbl,
     Mapping[Site],
     Data[Start],
     Data[End])
```